# python 3 subclassing in case of internal class

Tags: python, python-3.5, subclassing

In python 3.5.2, the following class hierarchy:

```
class Foobaz(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Baz(Foobaz):

    class Bar(Foo):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Bar, self).__init__()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Baz, self).__init__()
        self.bar = self.Bar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Baz()
```

instantiating the Baz class yields

```
    super(Bar, self).__init__()
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

Having an internal class subclassed directly from object - that is, no call to super - is just fine. I have no clue why. Can someone explain it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bar` isn't visible, it's a class variable. You'll need to be explicit:

```
super(Baz.Bar, self).__init__()
```

Take note that the no argument form of `super` takes care of this for you:

```
super().__init__()
```

works fine.

Comment: Great, thanks. This will make my life easier. But which of the two possible ways is the preferable one?

Comment: If you are writing code that tries to be version agnostic, go with the first. If you aren't go with the second.

Comment: Remove the comment about 'ideally'.  Using `type(self)` in super is a big mistake!

Comment: @wim It's one of those things I always forget due to never using Python 2 :)